# Will android default tts work on blackberry

Tags: blackberry-playbook, blackberry-android

I was trying to convert an android application using android tts service to blackberry. Using the blackberry command line tool I created the bar file and installed it in blackberry playbook simulator. But when I try to use the text to speech functionality its not working in the blackberry version. I am using the androids default tts service for this functionality. Will it work on blackberry ? Is that causing the issue. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

[TTS, VoIP, and SIP services are not supported](http://developer.blackberry.com/playbook/android/apisupport/unsupportedapi_playbook_software_features.html) by the BlackBerry Runtime for Android apps on BlackBerry PlayBook.